# Clojure: two different definitions of update-in in GitHub

Tags: git, clojure

I have been trying to reimplement update-in as a learning exercise, and have been using Clojure's core.clj GitHub to find a definitive answer. I have found two separate definitions of the function, one in the [Master](https://github.com/clojure/clojure/blob/master/src/clj/clojure/core.clj) branch:

```
(defn update-in
  ;; metadata removed
  {:added "1.0"
   :static true}
  ([m ks f & args]
     (let [up (fn up [m ks f args]
                (let [[k & ks] ks]
                  (if ks
                    (assoc m k (up (get m k) ks f args))
                    (assoc m k (apply f (get m k) args)))))]
       (up m ks f args))))
```

And one in the [010864f8ed...](https://github.com/clojure/clojure/blob/010864f8ed828f8d261807b7345f1a539c5b20df/src/clj/clojure/core.clj#L5939) tree:

```
(defn update-in
  ;; metadata removed
  {:added "1.0"
   :static true}
  ([m [k & ks] f & args]
   (if ks
     (assoc m k (apply update-in (get m k) ks f args))
     (assoc m k (apply f (get m k) args)))))
```

Presumably (though I'm not sure how to find out), the version in the non-Master tree is newer and not been brought into the Master. I've tried implementing the non-Master version in the REPL and it seem to work fine. I can see the arguments are slightly different, and calling `(doc update-in)` in REPL returns the same arguments as the tree's definition.

I'm also slightly confused as to why the definition in Master is more verbose than non-Master version, which seems to use established Clojure functions (i.e. nothing introduced in later versions).

Please can someone:

1. clarify what the two different versions are?
2. explain why the Master's more verbose definition exists when the tree's more succinct one works (albeit with slightly different args)? Has it just been refactored to work more efficiently?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The master is actually the most recent one, which can be see by looking at the result of *Blame* for both trees. In the case of the Master branch, you can see the commit that introduced the changes is called [*improve update-in perf*](https://github.com/clojure/clojure/commit/53b02ef20c32386c4b4e23e1018e1a19140fee06). I don't see any more information in the commit, which is frankly not good.

The patch introduces a local function which changes what is done when there is a non-null `ks` argument (the general case, when descending into keys). The recursive call to `update-in` through `apply` is replaced by a direct call to `up`.